# Dynamicly added dropdown menu in AngularJS + Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm writing a module that will create a dynamic menu on the fly. How to run a directive after adding new `<li>` with css class `dropdown` which is also added by ng-class.
The code:

```
angular.module('myapp', ['ui.bootstrap'])
.factory("menuService", ["$rootScope", function($rootScope) {
    "use strict";

    return { 
        menu: function() {
            $rootScope.globalMenu;
        },    
        setMenu: function(menu) {
            $rootScope.globalMenu = menu;
        }
    };

}])
.controller("MainController", ["$scope", "menuService",
    function($scope, menuService){

        menuService.setMenu([{href:"#", label:"Dropdown",
                                dropdown:[{href:"/edit", label:"Edit"}]},
                             {href:'/', label:'test'}]);

        $scope.bodyText = "Some text";


    }]);
```

This is the code in html

```
    <ul class="navbar-nav nav navbar-left">
        <li ng-repeat="menu_element in globalMenu" ng-class="{dropdown: menu_element.dropdown != undefined}">
            <a ng-href="{{menu_element.href}}" ng-class="{'dropdown-toggle': menu_element.dropdown != undefined}">
                {{menu_element.label}}
                <b class="caret" ng-if="menu_element.dropdown != undefined"></b>
            </a>
            <ul ng-if="menu_element.dropdown != undefined" class="dropdown-menu">
                <li ng-repeat="sub_element in $parent.menu_element.dropdown">
                    <a ng-href="{{sub_element.href}}">{{sub_element.label}}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Link to plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/pgH35mmsjLJqV4yJuSYq?p=preview

So what I want to do is the same or similar as for jQuery, there I would run `$("li.dropdown").dropdown()` after adding whole ul>li blocks. I'm new to Angular and I want to make this in the angular way.

I read about directives, how to use them. But I couldn't find how to apply directive in runtime. I've read about `transclude: element` in a directive (ui.bootstrap.dropdownToggle) doesn't have it enabled. I'm sure that there is a easy way, but couldn't find it myself...

Comment: It won't solve the question, but there's already a popular library for [Bootstrap AngularJS directives on github](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

Comment: Yes, I'm using it you can check it out on plunker that I've posted link to.

Comment: Didn't notice as you didn't do `module('myapp', ['ui-bootstrap'])`, anyhow, directives are picked up automatically by AngularJS, which checks the elements' attributes, for elements below the element with the `ng-app` attribute.

Comment: Yup, my bad, edited. So they are checked even for those that are added with ng-repeat and with class that is added by ng-class? Do you have a working example?

Comment: The example on the ui-bootstrap website is only one level deep, but yes. [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/WWickuov3JprFzlfhJhB?p=preview) ( At least, yes for ng-repeat, not sure about ng-class )

Comment: Thank you for your time, but in your example the class of dropdown-toggle is set statically, try with this: [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/zubwpYSH8q22glbkPiWN?p=preview) with ng-class unfortunately it does not work

Comment: The easy way out could be to wrap it in an element with `ng-show` around it, from what I can find on the internet `ng-class` doesn't apply the directive

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved!

I've finally made it with `ng-if` and `ng-repeat-start`. With help in comments, I've found that `ng-class` does not run directives.

```
    <ul class="navbar-nav nav navbar-left">
        <span ng-repeat-start="menu_element in globalMenu"></span>
        <li ng-if="menu_element.dropdown !== undefined">
              <a ng-href="{{menu_element.href}}" class="dropdown-toggle">
                  {{menu_element.label}}
                  <b class="caret" ></b>
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li ng-repeat="sub_element in $parent.menu_element.dropdown">
                      <a ng-href="{{sub_element.href}}">{{sub_element.label}}</a>
                  </li>
              </ul>
        </li>
        <li ng-if="menu_element.dropdown === undefined">
              <a ng-href="{{menu_element.href}}">
                {{menu_element.label}}
              </a>
        </li>
        <span ng-repeat-end></span>
    </ul>
```

Working example on [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ppvSVsBaSvo86iHZDBNQ?p=preview). Something happened with the css on Plunker, yesterday it was working... but still it works.

Answer (score 1):

Nice, this helped me along the way. I've a slight variation on your theme.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li ng-repeat='link in menu track by $index' ng-class='[{dropdown:link.sub}]'>
    /* normal menu */
    <a ng-if='!link.sub' ng-bind='link.id' ng-click='jump(link.to)'></a>
    /* dropdown menu */
    <a ng-if='link.sub' class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
      <span ng-bind='link.id'></span>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu inverse-dropdown">
        /* and repeat for the submenu */
        <li ng-repeat='slink in link.menu track by $index'>
          <a ng-bind='slink.id' ng-click='jump(slink.to)'></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

My menu array is a list of

```
{id:'name', to:n}
```

where n points to an array listing some html I push into the page. When there is a sub menu the menu array element is

```
{id:'name', sub:true, menu:[{id:'name', to:n}, etc.]}
```

I tried ui-bootstrap but never got my head around it.